# Autofill not working when id select from drop down list

Tags: javascript, php, autofill

I am trying to automatically fill all fields of my form when I entered input in first field. It works absolutely fine when I manually enter value in the first field. But when I used drop down list and select one value for first input field, other fields do not fill out automatically. Scode is the field which I want to select and value in other input fields automatically come. Perhaps cant  bind an click event to the option element.

Here is my Php-HTM Form Code :-

```
<form method="POST" action="invoice.php">
    <tr id="TRow" class="d-none">
            <td>
                <Select class="scode form-control text-end" name="scode[]" id="user_id" onkeyup="GetDetail(this.closest('tr'))" onchange="Calc(this);">
                    <option value="0">Select Gender</option>
                    <?php
                        include('db.php');
                        $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM machine1");
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                        {
                            echo '<option value="'.$row[''].'">'.$row['user_id'].'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" class="qty form-control text-end" name="qty[]"  id="ccc" onchange="Calc(this);"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="price1 form-control text-end"  name="discunt[]"  id="ddd" onchange="Calc(this);"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="discunt form-control text-end" name="discunt[]"  id="eee" onchange="Calc(this);"></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Javascript code

```
<script>

// onkeyup event will occur when the user
// release the key and calls the function
// assigned to this event
function GetDetail(row) {
    let str = row.querySelector(".scode").value;
    if (str.length == 0) {
        row.querySelector(".qty").value = "";
        row.querySelector(".price").value = "";
        row.querySelector(".discunt").value = "";

        return;
    } else {
        // Creates a new XMLHttpRequest object
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            // Defines a function to be called when
            // the readyState property changes
            if (this.readyState == 4 &&
            this.status == 200) {

            // Typical action to be performed
            // when the document is ready
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            // Returns the response data as a
            // string and store this array in
            // a variable assign the value
            // received to first name input field



            row.querySelector(".qty").value = myObj[0];
            row.querySelector(".price").value = myObj[1];
            row.querySelector(".discunt").value = myObj[2]; 

            }
        };

        // xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gfg.php?user_id=" + str, true);

        // Sends the request to the server
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. You cannot have a `form` at that position within the `table` - either the entire `table` must be wholly contained within the `form` **or** the entire `form` must be wholly contained within a single table-cell!

Comment: i posted shortcut code. as i said everything working fine when i entered manually. but when i chnage input field o drop down, then its stop autofil other fields

Comment: @Alive sory i pasted short cup code earlier, now I correct code with tr tags. Please check and suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) You need to have your HTML wrapped into `<table></table>` and it needs to be inside `<form>`

b) For select the `onChange` method will work, not the `onkeyup` so remove it.

c) `row.querySelector(".price").value = myObj[1];` needs to be `row.querySelector(".price1").value = myObj[1];` as you have class `price1`

d) Create a variable of `row` and then use this variable into else part.

Sample working code:

```js
function GetDetail(row) {
  var currenttr = row;
  let str = currenttr.querySelector(".scode").value;
  if (str.length == 0) {
    currenttr.querySelector(".qty").value = "";
    currenttr.querySelector(".price").value = "";
    currenttr.querySelector(".discunt").value = "";

    return;
  } else {

    currenttr.querySelector(".qty").value = str;
    currenttr.querySelector(".price1").value = str;
    currenttr.querySelector(".discunt").value = str;

  }

}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="invoice.php">
  <table>
    <tr id="TRow" class="d-none">
      <td>
        <Select class="scode form-control text-end" name="scode[]" id="user_id" onChange="GetDetail(this.closest('tr'))">
          <option value="0">Select Gender</option>
          <option value="1">Female</option>
          <option value="2">Male</option>
          <option value="3">Transgender</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty form-control text-end" name="qty[]" id="ccc" onchange="Calc(this);"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price1 form-control text-end" name="discunt[]" id="ddd" onchange="Calc(this);"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="discunt form-control text-end" name="discunt[]" id="eee" onchange="Calc(this);"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

---